# Setting timer of seconds and milli seconds

Tags: javascript, timer

```js
var count = 24000,
  running = true,
  secondsNode = document.getElementById("seconds"),
  millisecondsNode = document.getElementById("milliseconds"),
  mOld,
  mNew;

function draw() {
  if (count > 0 && running) {
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    mNew = new Date().getTime();
    count = count - mNew + mOld;
    count = count >= 0 ? count : 0;
    mOld = mNew;
    secondsNode.innerHTML = Math.floor(count / 1000);
    millisecondsNode.innerHTML = count % 1000;
  }
}
mOld = new Date().getTime();
draw();

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 32: // PLAY
      if (running) {
        running = false;
      } else {
        running = true;
        mOld = new Date().getTime();
        draw();
      }
      break;
    case 82: // RESET
      count = 24000;
      secondsNode.innerHTML = 24;
      millisecondsNode.innerHTML = 0;
      running = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<p><span id="seconds">4</span> secs and <span id="milliseconds">000</span> milliseconds</p>
```

This is the code for timer. Here what is happening is the timer starting from 24 seconds and ending in 0. But what I need is I need to start this timer from 0 to 4 seconds. Can we do that? If that so please help. Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this, you need to change the time decrementer to an incrementer by using:

```
count = count + mNew - mOld;
```

Also, you need to ensure that your conditions and checks stop when you reach `4000` instead of `0`.

See working example below:

```js
var count = 0,
  running = false,
  secondsNode = document.getElementById("seconds"),
  millisecondsNode = document.getElementById("milliseconds"),
  mOld,
  mNew;

function isElementInViewport(el) { // run function to check if the element is in the viewport
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return rect.bottom > 0 && rect.right > 0 && rect.left < (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) && rect.top < (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight);
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() { // everytime we scroll
  if(isElementInViewport(secondsNode)) { // check if the p element is on the screen - if it is then:
    running = true; // start the timer (unpause it)
    mOld = new Date().getTime();
    draw();
  } else { // if the element is off the screen then
    running = false; // pause the timer
  }
});

function draw() {
  if (count < 4000 && running) { // change to check count < 4000 to keep running
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    mNew = new Date().getTime();
    count = count + mNew - mOld; // change to increment the count
    count = count >= 4000 ? 4000 : count; // change stop the clock from incrementing
    mOld = mNew;
    secondsNode.innerHTML = Math.floor(count / 1000);
    millisecondsNode.innerHTML = count % 1000;
  }
}


window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 32: // PLAY (space)
      if (running) {
        running = false;
      } else {
        running = true;
        mOld = new Date().getTime();
        draw();
      }
      break;
    case 82: // RESET (r)
      count = 0;
      secondsNode.innerHTML = 0;
      millisecondsNode.innerHTML = 0;
      running = true;
  }
});
```

```css
.other {
  padding-bottom: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="other"></div>
<p><span id="seconds">4</span> secs and <span id="milliseconds">000</span> milliseconds</p>

<div class="other"></div>
```